# Model dropping List<>s after DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a search criteria building page. In addition to several string and numerical type fields, there are several "multiple choice" options.

I'm using the `[Get]` signature without parameters(pass the `CriteriaModel` to the view) >> `[Post]` signature with `CriteriaModel` parameter (redirect to searching controller)

I've built lightweight option classes (just value, name pairs) and am populating several `List<>` with the primitive options.

Using `Html.DropDownListFor`, I'm able to get them to display.

...but...

When I enter the `[Post]` version, the `List<>`s are all set to null and empty. Further, the other criteria fields supposed to be populated afterwards are also default and empty.

Technically, I don't need a whole list of values back - if I could even just have the index of the selected value - but I'm up against a wall here.

Pertinent model data:

```
    public class CriteriaModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Owner Name")]
        public string OwnerName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Subdivision")]
        public List<Subdivision> Subdivision { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("PIN")]
        public string PIN { get; set; }
    }
    public class Subdivision
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Pertinent controller code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CriteriaModel criteria = new CriteriaModel();
        ...fill in the Subdivisions...
        View(criteria);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(CriteriaModel search_criteria)
    {
        return View("Search obtained" + search_criteria.Subdivision.First().Name);
    }
```

And pertinent View markup:

```
@model REOModern.Models.CriteriaModel
...bunch of HTML...
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subdivision)
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Subdivision, new SelectList(Model.Subdivision, "ID", "Name", Model.Subdivision.First().ID))
...other HTML...
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Index">Search</button>
```

I should clarify: I know that my 'return View("Search obtained" + ...' will fail, but it should show the piece of data that I need. The problem is it's a null reference exception. Until I can fix that, there's no point in building a user-friendly View for submitted search criteria.

Comment: is this a web page? If so check for IsPostBack on page load

Comment: It's MVC. I guess I didn't specify that, my bad.

Comment: Some code would help tremendously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC does not repopulate the `List<>` elements.

You would split the selected value out into another property of the model.

So in your model, include something like this

```
public int SelectedValue { get; set; }
```

Then for your `Html.DropDownListFor` helper you would use

```
Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedValue, Model.DropDownList, new { /* htmlAttributes */ });
```

Comment: I've tried that, but the Index property is 0 by the end of the [Post] action

Comment: @CrüjenGeist, just to be sure, in the HTML code you didn't include, you are including your form fields in an actual `form` tag using `Html.BeginForm`?

Comment: Yeah. It is several rows up.

Comment: @CrüjenGeist, check your browsers developer tools and see what is being included in the form post and include it in your question. If your other form fields are being left out as well, then the issue is probably something other than just your select list.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was trying to fix it, started moving around the submit button - there was a <form> tag nested within the @Html.BeginForm, closed before the button.

Answer (score 0):

Of course they're empty. The only data that exists in your post action is that which was posted via the form. Since the entire dropdown list, itself, was not posted, merely a selected item(s), the lists are empty. For anything like this, you need to rerun the same logic in your post action to populate them as you did in your get action. It's usually better to factor out this logic into a private method on your controller that both actions can use:

```
private void PopulateSomeDropDownList(SomeModel model)
{
    // logic here to construct dropdown list
    model.SomeDropDownList = dropdownlist;
}
```

Then in your actions:

```
PopulateSomeDropDownList(model);
return View(model);
```

Comment: So how would I get their selection from the DropDownList in the Post action? That's all I really want

Comment: That should come through on the post. Typically, you'd render your dropdown list like: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeProperty, Model.MySelectList)`. The selected item, then, would be set on `SomeProperty` on your model.